# How to see data that post out for using libcurl at fiddler?

Tags: libcurl, fiddler

I would like to post data to website
and I use below sample code and library to run
(https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html)

I use "Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger" to monitor
data that post out...but I tried many times and 
can't see any data at Telerik...

How to modify code or setting of Telerik that 
see data that post out??

Thank you for your great help!!!

Comment: I using "DLL Windows SSPI" Configuration at libcurl to post out data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that data out from libcurl itself by using the [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) callback. A full example using that option and some handy functions you can copy and paste exist in the [debug.c example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/debug.html), provided in the libcurl docs.